# MySQL Format String with columns

Tags: mysql

I am currently working on our MySQL Database and am in need of help. Would be happy if you have a solution! :)

We are generating automatic invoices with text. The text is very long and contains customerinformation and other fields of the database.

Currently we are using a long concat function which is so long that you can't see through. I would like to have a function that takes a string with placeholders ([like php sprintf function](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.sprintf.php)) with values and formats the text.

For example (pseudocode)

```
FILLTEXT("Customer %s has payed invoice %s on %s",customername,invoicenumber,invoicepaydate) as Invoice_text
```

(We are using a lot of columns and a much longer text, I just wanted to do a quick example).

I am very grateful for any help or advices!
Thanks

Comment: Use the CONCAT function https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

Comment: I worry that you're confusing data display with data storage and retrieval.